# strtotime wrong value after I added 1 month

Tags: php

this line gives me the correct value:

```
echo strtotime(date('d.m.Y 00:00:00'));
```

Output:

```
1623362400
```

Converted:

```
Fri Jun 11 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Now I would like to get the same, but +1 month.
I tried this:

```
echo strtotime('+1 month', date('d.m.Y 00:00:00'));
```

Output:

```
2678411
```

Converted:

```
Sun Feb 01 1970 01:00:11 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: _“Where is my fault?”_ - first of all, in not having proper PHP error reporting enabled. This should have given you a `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered`, resp. a fatal error in PHP 8.

Comment: The second argument to `strtotime` is a *UNIX timestamp*, not a string date…

Comment: okay, and why it works in the first case with a string date?

Comment: Because the *first* argument to `strtotime` is a string.

Comment: The manual explains it quite well… https://www.php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using well the first strtotime() param. Passing 2 arguments ask the function to "compare" and use the second param as a baseTimestamp.

For the result you want, you only need the first param, and have to specify you want "+1 month" before. You can do it concatenating the string with date() result :

```
echo strtotime(date('d.m.Y 00:00:00').' +1 month');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to nest string operations or convert back and forth:

```
$t = strtotime('midnight +1 month');
echo date('r', $t);
```